# Разделить HTTP-адрес, ipv4 и ipv6 адреса

Tags: c++, c, http, winsock, winsock2

Можно ли гарантированно, "разделить" HTTP-адрес, ipv4 и ipv6 адреса ?
Ну, то есть, есть к примеру 6 строк:

-"https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"

-"ru.stackoverflow.com"

-"www.ru.stackoverflow.com"

-"95.173.136.162"

-"2a03:2880:f10a:83:face:b00c:0:25de"

-"2a00:1450:4010:c0e::65"

Вот есть ли алгоритм, который позволит точно сказать, что в первых трех строках - это http-адресс, в 4 строке - это ipv4, а в 5 и 6 строках - ipv6 ?

Если бы не http-адреса, то все просто конечно: если есть "." - значит ipv4, если есть ":" - то ipv6. Но, в http - есть и "." и ":". Вот, что то не могу сообразить.

Comment: IP4 - это всегда три числа не более 255, разделенные точками. Да, можно и запросить `http://123.22.34.18/index.html`, но просто `123.22.34.18` - точно ip4.

Comment: Если это строки - то определяют или програмно ифами/циклами, или как вариант - regex. Если это DNS то там есть признак.

Comment: @Harry, Но проблем в другом, как определить, что вот это "123.22.34.18" - это текстовое представление ipv4, а вот это - "www.mac.uoz.ru" - это http - адрес?

Comment: Никак. У одного сайта может быть несколько ай-пи (тот же SO). И у одного айпи может быть несколько сайтов. И первое и второе, и первое плюс второе - незапрещено. Первое и второе - часто встречал. Только в отдельных часных случаях, сравнив с DNS-таблицей можно достоверно сказать что этот айпи принадлежит этому имени.

Comment: Я же написал - считайте, что если просто 4 числа не более 255, разделенные точками - то это ip4. Я правильно понимаю вашу задачу: есть строка, и надо понять, что именно она собой представляет?

Comment: См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871737/9123401

Comment: @Harry, что именно `gethostbyname()` (а это единственный реальный арбитр) посчитает **правильным IP V4** разбирать лень, но точно *не только четыре десятичных числа, размером не более 255, разделенных точками* (количество допустимых форматов записи ipv4 намного больше)

Comment: @Optimus1, вам для начала надо проверять наличие префикса `all_isalnum://`. Если он есть, то далее текст до `/` это адрес. Валидность адреса лучше всего проверяет стандартная функция `gethostbyname()`. Однако, тут есть такая засада, что если в принципе валидный символический адрес вашему DNS сейчас в принципе не доступен, то gethostbyname вернет ошибку. Как все это вместе работает, можете покопать [тут](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/network)

Comment: @avp Как я понимаю, под "правильным" адресом вы понимаете только "существующий"?...

Comment: @Harry, необязательно, это может быть не существующий адрес.

Comment: Я о том и писал, поэтому и спрашиваю у @avp, что **он** понимает под правильным адресом...

Comment: @Harry, `"под "правильным" адресом вы понимаете только "существующий"?"` -- нет, я имел в виду именно синтаксически правильный адрес (imho это адрес из компонент, разделенных точкой, состоящих из ascii букв, цифр и знака `-` (может что-то еще из похожих символов тоже допускается)), не важно, занесен он сейчас в какой-то DNS или нет.

Comment: @avp Мы говорили об адресе IP V4 - ваш текст: "*что именно `gethostbyname()` (а это единственный реальный арбитр) посчитает **правильным IP V4***" - я о нем.

Comment: @Harry, посмотрел поглубже. Все же зависит от конкретной реализации  `gethostbyname()` (вызывает она `inet_pton()` или `inet_aton()`). Из manpage `inet_pton` -- *`"Unlike inet_aton(3) and inet_addr(3), inet_pton() supports IPv6 addresses.  On the other hand, inet_pton() accepts only IPv4 addresses in dotted-decimal notation, whereas inet_aton(3) and inet_addr(3) allow the more general numbers-and-dots notation  (hexadecimal and octal number formats, and formats that don't require all four bytes to be explicitly written)."`*

Comment: Т.о. сейчас при анализе строки на правильность записи IP V4 (в виде числа) программист должен принимать осознанное решение, какую из форм записи (только новую, или "старые" тоже) считать валидной. Как всегда, зависит от задачи (истории используемых данных и т.п.). Очевидно, что для совсем новых приложений, лучше забить на тяжкий груз прошлого, не выпендриваться и делать как вы сказали -- *4 десятичных числа до 255, разделенных точками*

Comment: Давненько я не брал в руки шашку -) (не писал сетевые программы). @Optimus1, обратите внимание на [man  getaddrinfo](http://ru.manpages.org/getaddrinfo/3) (возможно как раз эта функция с параметрами по умолчанию наилучшим образом разбирает адреса)